# More than one instance Oracle XE

Tags: database, oracle, virtual-machine, windows-virtual-pc

I have a vm running Windows 7, which I use for testing web applications in IE8 and IE9. Also, I use this vm to run Oracle XE.

I have a java system that will have some changes. These changes will modify the database, but I need to keep the old version of the system and the old database structure. I was thinking of using more than one instance of Oracle and apply the new version of it.

Problems:

1. An vm Windows 7 has an average 30gb and I only have 17GB free.
2. I'm using Oracle XE, so I can't have more than one instance.

Any good idea?

Comment: If you're only using this for developing and testing you can probably use a regular version, like Enterprise Edition, instead of XE.  I'd recommend you read the license on Oracle's download site (which unfortunately is down right now, so I can't give you a link).

Comment: I tried this solution. Unfortunately I could not install correctly. I read the license, and I am using for dev only. So, it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "An vm Windows 7 has an average 30gb and I only have 17GB free."

It's 2012, almost 2013.  We can buy [32GB thumb drives for a pittance](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=32gb%20sandisk%20usb&tag=googhydr-21&index=aps&hvadid=14377522436&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=19879262771695796002&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&ref=pd_sl_37gimiwy5x_b).  If you really can't get hold of a server with more disk space you'll just have to externalize.  The performance might suck a bit, but presumably you're just interested in functional testing.

Comment: Yes... I did it. I bought a 1TB external hd. Thanks.